# django url is loading in the console ,but the function in the view is not working

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

> [26/Aug/2019 09:51:08] "GET /update HTTP/1.1" 200 32972

my basic url on the above and after ajax call below.

> [26/Aug/2019 09:51:11] "GET /updateline?client_response=true%20
>   HTTP/1.1" 200 32972

## views.py

```
def update_line(request):
     if request.method == 'GET':
        print("okey")
        #username = request.POST.get('username', None)
        label =  ["INDIA", "PAK", "Europe", "Latin America", "North America"]
        data = json.dumps(label)

        return JsonResponse({"label":data})
```

## jscript

```
$("button").click(function(){
                                  $.get(
                                  { url: '{% url "update_line" %}',
                                  //dataType: 'json',
                                  //method: "GET",
                                  data : {
                                      client_response : "true ",
                                      },
                                  error: function(e){
                                        alert('fail');},
                                  success: function(data){
                                  var  dt =data.label
                                    alert(dt);
                                     addData();

                                  }});
                                });
```

## url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.HomePageView.as_view()),# views -Homepageview()
    url(r'chart', views.charts1,name='chart'),
    url(r'blank', views.blank_page,name='blank'),
    url(r'update', views.update_page,name='update'),
    url(r'updateline',views.update_line,name='update_line')
    #url(r'^$', views.HomePageView.as_view()),
]
```

## using ajax insteadof get

```
  $.ajax(
                                  { url: '{% url "update_line" %}',
                                  //dataType: 'json',
                                  method: "GET",
                                  data : {
                                      client_response : "true ",
                                      },
                                  error: function(e){
                                        alert('fail');},
                                  success: function(data){
                                  var  dt =data.label
                                    alert(dt);
                                     addData();

                                  }});
                                });
```

Comment: use pdb to check whether your view is working or not.

Comment: First of all remove the comment from `method: GET`, secondly use `$.ajax` insted of get

Comment: i already tried this one $ .ajax, no use. I don't know what is wrong with the code.

Comment: Also, do NOT apply `json.dumps()` on your `label` variable - `JsonResponse` will encode the data, so you end up with doubly serialized data

Comment: print("okey") is not working in this case, the view is not even loading on ajax call.

Comment: @RohitSharma you are right, changing my view function name and URL solved everything. Anyway thanks.

Comment: @Sajanraj Please upvote if you feel your problem is resolved. Thanks

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the view function and worked after changing the name.
Do not use the same name or edit once created.